# Logout on tab close but not page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, onbeforeunload

I know that this question has been asked probably too many times before but I couldn't find a solution that would fit my needs, and also the cases described by the other OPs are slightly different than mine.

1. I have a Single Page Application so in app navigations (clicking on anchors etc.) is not an issue.
2. I need to logout a user when he closes the browser's tab or navigates away: e.g. another domain.
3. I **do not want** to logout a user if he simply refreshes the browser

(the logout is done via POSTing to a specific url to the api server, the request could be synchronous or using Beacon API - it's not a problem).

The problem is however how to distinguish a refresh from navigating away or closing browser tab.

- I know that in the `onbeforeunload` event handler it's impossible to know what is the new target url that the browser is trying to navigate to.
- Detecting that a user hit F5/Cmd+R/Ctrl+R is not enough as someone might just click on the browser toolbar button to refresh. Or choose to refresh from the View menu in Safari e.g.

I thought about logging to localStorage a timestamp of the last `beforeunload` event and then compare it when the page loads and set that if the two happened in less then 2 seconds e.g. then it was probably a refresh. But then again someone might tamper with localstorage and Private mode Safari has no localstorage...

The solution could involve both client changes and server changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: check this:http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: My backend is in nodejs

Comment: Relying on an event to cause a session close isn't very safe.  If it is crucial that the session be closed immediately upon page close, then perhaps traditional sessions are not your best means of implementing security.  You would likely be better served using a long polling/socket based solution which continuously monitors the session (like what banks use on their sites).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that socket based solution? Or perhaps provide a link to an article I read more about it?

Comment: @kamilkp I'm facing the same issue. How did you resolve this issue?